# How to manipulate multiple paths with array structure in Polygon react google maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps, react-google-maps-api

Hello i am using the `react-google-maps/api` library and i want to map some coordinates in my `Google Map` using the `Polygon` component. So far i have manage to map `Polygons` in my map with holes like this:

```
return polyline.location.map((outerCoords, polyInd) => {
........
<Polygon
  key={`polyline-${i}-${polyInd}`}
  paths={[outerCoords, innerCoords[0], innerCoords[1]}
.........
```

And the result is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyaaP.png).

My problem is that i don't know each time the `innerCoords` array length so i want to add the inner coordinates some how dynamic. How i can do this?
I was thinking using this `Array.prototype.flat()` but this is not solve my problem, (Map without holes). Also i don't know if i can somehow `map()` the `innerCoords` array and then use `Polygon` inside, but i think with this way i will see only one polygon hole at the time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think i solve my problem, i just did this:

```
return polyline.location.map((outerCoords, polyInd) => {
  ........
  <Polygon
    key={`polyline-${i}-${polyInd}`}
    paths={[outerCoords, ...innerCoords]}
  .........
```